# Selenium.click Timed out waiting for action to finish

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc

I'm running selenium RC with Java in Eclipse. The issue I'm having is with the selenium.click command. The link I click on loads a new page. Sometimes that takes 5 seconds and sometimes it'll take 2-3 minutes. Each time I see the page load and immediately after my test fails and I get the message "Timed out waiting for action to finish."

I've tried to instead use selenium.isElementPresent to check for the page being loaded. However, when I run in debug mode I notice it never gets past the selenium.click to even get to the point of checking for the element. From what I understand there is a wait built into the selenium.click command. So my question is, does anyone know how to ignore that built in wait so I can instead use the selenium.isElementPresent instead?

```
selenium.click(Link);
for (int i = 0; i < 60 ; i++) {
    if (selenium.isElementPresent(Home)) {
       break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I've also tried using a selenium.open to go directly to the URL and skip the link completely and then use the selenium.isElementPresent to verify the page has loaded. I get the same issue there where it never actually gets to the for loop before failing with the same error message.

Comment: you never go to the `for` statement. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < 60 ; i++)`

Comment: I just noticed that. the typo was in the question but not the actual code so I fixed it here. The same issue still happens though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue. I just wrapped the click command with a try/catch so that the error was caught, then did an assert title and checked for the expected text on the page.

Comment: Actually surrounding it with a try/catch worked great. I can still catch the error but not have it fail my test so I can then use other methods of confirming the page loaded. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you incorporate this method/function into your code.

```
    public static void WaitForPageToLoad(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2400);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

        IJavaScriptExecutor javascript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (javascript == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("driver", "Driver must support javascript execution");

        wait.Until((d) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string readyState = javascript.ExecuteScript("if (document.readyState) return document.readyState;").ToString();
                return readyState.ToLower() == "complete";
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                //Window is no longer available
                return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to get browser");
            }
            catch (WebDriverException e)
            {
                //Browser is no longer available
                return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to connect");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

At times selenium's .Click() will wait for a self reference response.  To surpass that, and to let your test proceed, I would do the following with your code.

```
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

    try{ selenium.click(Link); }
    catch(WebDriverException) {}
    WaitForPageToLoad(driver); 
    //look for your element.
```

Combine that with an implicit wait, and once the JavaScript reports back that the page has finished loading, you can then look for your element. I find it much more dynamic than chancing selenium not finding the element within 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the nature of the applicaiton you're testing. If the click action, loads a new page then you can use selenium's waitForPageToLoad command as follows:

```
selenium.click(Link);
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
```

**NOTE:** The parameter is the timeout value in milliseconds. So this will wait up to 60 seconds for the page to load.

Probably the best workaround for that click and wait functionality is to use Selenium's waitForCondition method as such:

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"Home\")", 60000);
```

Selenium runs the isElementPresent method continuously until it returns true or it reaches the timeout value given as the second parameter. In addition, the `selenium.waitForCondition` can run `selenium.isTextPresent` to check if text is present on screen before moving on with the script.

Comment: Actually the problem I'm running into here is that my tests never get past the selenium.click command to even get to the selenium.waitForPageToLoad or the selenium.waitForCondition. The selenium.click seems to have a built in wait that I can't seem to get around to use any other method of verifying the page has loaded.

Comment: Im here in 2019 and having this issue, did you found how to solve it?

Comment: Still waiting in 2024 :(